# How will "bundle install --deployment" work in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

For gem dependency management in production `bundle install --deployment` used to isolate all gems into `vendor/bundle`.
As of rails 4, `vendor` directory is removed. How will `--deployment` flag work?Will this option be removed too?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only `vendor/plugins` is being deprecated. Rest will continue to work.

Comment: So what would be importance of `--deployment` flag.It's very handy in rails 3.x when `bundler` can't run as root and this flag will resolve gem dependencies by isolating gems in `vendor/plugin`.I mean can we still bundle app specific gems in rails 4?

Comment: Yes, I think it vendors in "vendor/bundle", if i am not mistaken.